# laravel 5.4 - socket io need csrf token to send ajax to laravel server , how to get that?

Tags: ajax, laravel, socket.io, csrf

My socket io want to send ajax to laravel server , but I need the csrf token to set to my ajax header , how to do that?

I have found a page seems discuss this ,
[socketio_client_authentication_using_laravel_session_data](http://nonamez.name/en/post/socketio_client_authentication_using_laravel_session_data),

```
const SOCKET_PARAMS  = 'laravel_session_cookie={{ $_COOKIE[config('session.cookie')] }}&csrf_token={{ csrf_token() }}'
```

but this code make my ide compile error , how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is probably caused by the quotes. Just change them like this and try again:

```
const SOCKET_PARAMS  = "laravel_session_cookie={{ $_COOKIE[config('session.cookie')] }}&csrf_token={{ csrf_token() }}";
```

Remember that PHP does not distinguish between strings and characters, so you could combine them as you want.

If you need more information check the [PHP string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax) documentation.

Hope this helps you.